# Trying to enable XML language in Twig templates in PhpStorm

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, twig, phpstorm

In my project I have `*.xml.twig` files that render XML using the Twig templating engine. Anyone figured out how to enable both XML and Twig code support at the same time in PhpStorm?

I tried `Settings -> File Types`, but only one type can be applied to a file type at a time. The funny thing is, if I change settings, there is a few seconds when PhpStorm is reindexing the project and both XML and  Twig rules are applied to a file, but when it finishes reindexing, it removes one of the languages.

I also thought about language injections, but that feature seems to only work with strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Template Data Languages`
2. Find your file(s) there and assign `XML` in right column (can also be applied to the whole folder -- all files and sub folders will inherit this setting).

This will make XML as primary outer language instead of default HTML.

Comment: Since PhpStorm 8.0 and IntelliJ IDEA 14:
`Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Template Data Languages`
Otherwise, still works.

Comment: what if you want to use both ? XML for *.xml.twig and HTML for *.html.twig ?

Comment: @Flozza Huh? I do not understand your issue. HTML is a default language inside Twig templates already. if you need XML -- you adjust it as described above.